# iPhone 3.5 size for separate storyboards?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, storyboard

```
- (UIStoryboard *)grabStoryboard {
    // determine screen size
    int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
    UIStoryboard *storyboard;

    switch (screenHeight) {
        // iPhone 5
        case 320:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone4Storyboard" bundle:nil]
                ;
            break;
        // iPhone 6
        case 375:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone6Storyboard" bundle:nil];
            break;
        // iPhone 6 Plus
        case 414:
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            break;
        default:
            // It's an iPad
            storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainiPad" bundle:nil];
            break;
    }

    return storyboard;
}
```

I use that code to make my app run on iPhone 5, 6, 6 plus and iPad. Now, I want to make it support the iPhone 4 size, or rather, the 3.5 screen. What code do I put in? Also, Objective-C code, not swift.

Autolayout is terrible, so don't give answers about it. Can someone tell what code do I have to use instead?

Comment: Is AutoLayout not an option for this app?  It would avoid all of this.

Comment: no, i don't want auto layout, so what can i do instead? like what code do i put in app delegate.m

Comment: Just keep one thing in mind - using your approach of using screen size-specific storyboards is far more work to maintain and it prevents you from supporting multitasking on supported iPads. And it's more work each time Apple comes out with a new device with a different screen size.

Comment: The sizes in your code don't match reality. The iPhone 5's screen height is not 320 (that's its width). And the values for the other iPhone are wrong too. Why don't you run your app is each of the different simulators and see what height value you actually get. Then you will know what values to use in your `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if( UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone ){
            CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
            CGFloat screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

            if( screenHeight < screenWidth ){
                screenHeight = screenWidth;
            }

     if( screenHeight > 480 && screenHeight < 667 ){
                    //NSLog(@"iPhone 5/5s");

                } else if ( screenHeight > 480 && screenHeight < 736 ){
                    //NSLog(@"iPhone 6");

                } else if ( screenHeight > 480 ){
                    //NSLog(@"iPhone 6 Plus");

                } else {
                    // NSLog(@"iPhone 4/4s");

                }
```

Comment: Why are you checking for a height of 480 for the 6+?